# How to fix firebase_ui_firestore [Analysis Issue]?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

[This error in the image below occurs when trying to build the app.]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QibXK.png)

Note: In pub.dev [firebase_ui_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_firestore/score) there is the same error pointed out!

I have tried `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` which gave no positive result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pubspec.yaml, replace firebase_ui_firestore: 1.6.0 with:

```
  firebase_ui_firestore:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Flutter.git
      path: packages/firebase_ui_firestore
```

They have fixed it but version is not published yet.